# Solr - Creating files with searchresults

Tags: solr

I just set up a Solr-Server on a TomCat-Servlet. Everything works fine, my index contains about 810.000 products with several data.

But now I´m facing a problem. To search the index I used the URL `"http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/"` which gives me always the right results. Now things get too complicated for a newbie like me. The queries shall be sent by another system to my servlet (how can this be handled?) and I need to resend the results in a xml-file (so the other system can handle it).

Any suggestions on how I can implement it? The main problem is to save the results in a file and search the index without using the `"http://localhost:8080/solr/admin"` interface. Is there somithing similar like the `post.jar` in the example dictionary for sending queries to the server? I read some stuff about requesthandler and so on, but I don´t really understand how to work with it.

Comment: What language (Java, PHP, Python, ..) do you want to use to get results form Solr? For some there are existing libraries to do that for you

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll have a requestHandler registered, and can be accessed through:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=<query string>
```

The Admin interface is a separate location for browsing the state of the server as well as querying data in a more interactive mode.

The format of the query string depends on which requestHandler has been registered. It might be (e)dismax, which will by default allow you to do "regular" search such as "word1 word2 word3", or it might be the standard query parser, which will use a syntax like "field:value" to do queries.

Solr will then by default respond with a result in an XML format, and you might use another queryResponseWriter to alter the output (to JSON or POJO, etc). See the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) for more information.

Comment: Sorry I dont really got it yet. Maybe I didn´t explain the problem correctly. I don´t understand the API of Solr. For now, I just use a Internetbrowser to search and display the results. Any system shall call a .bat file (or an application) which has to send a query string to the Solr server. The result (has to be a xml FILE (!!!!)) should be resend to this system. How can I execute a query without using the Internet browser and recieve the result in a file? The requestHandler display the result in my internet browser and don´t save it as a file, which can be sent back. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Now i read something about using a phpscript to resolve the results instead of using the internet browser. Is this the way I have to face the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solr's default query handler can be accessed at:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=<query string>
```

Just hit that url from your application and you'll receive an XML response.  Then you just write that response to your file.

Solr is mature enough that a lot of languages have libraries or modules to facilitate the process.

- PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.solr.php
- Java: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj
- Python: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPython
- Ruby: http://sunspot.github.com/